# P4Java sync to head revision

Tags: java, synchronization, revision, head, p4java

The Sync API in P4Java is pretty straightforward right?

client.sync(FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList("//depot/test/..."), new SyncOptions(forcesync, false, false, false));

The problem is that, when "forcesync" is true, it works well.  However, when it's false, the sync operation does NOT get latest revision, even though I add "#head" after "//depot/test/...".

Could you please help me on this?

Thanks a lot,
Michael

Comment: Well, got it..  It's because I try to sync a bunch of clients on different machines using the same "Client Name", so the first one is supposed to be synced, but the rest ones are not.  Bonehead hah?